# Google Spreadsheet COUNTIF TODAY()?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

Is there any way to `COUNTIF` it's the current date?

For example I have a spreadsheet with work orders, once the employee starts the work order it captures a time stamp, after the work order is completed it is moved to an archive, well I wanted to create a summary sheet that tells me how many orders we have done for that date, the format of the time stamp is:

> ```
> 2/19/2014 17:10:20
> ```

So basically I need a `COUNTIF` to count the column for the current date.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to apply a function first on the range, which then makes `COUNTIF` not an appropriate function to count those dates matching 'today'. You can use `SUMPRODUCT` instead:

```
=arrayformula(SUMPRODUCT(1*(INT(A1:A100)=TODAY())))
```

`INT` strips out the time from the datetime.

Comment: Works perfect, and it was staring me right in the face, thank you for teaching me =)

Comment: Nice answer, though sumproduct within arrayformula is redundant, since using sumproduct with one argument is just a hack to avoid typing ctrl-shift-enter in Excel, which is accomplished with arrayformula in Google.  Either of these would also work: `=ArrayFormula(SUM(1*(INT(A1:A100)=TODAY())))` or `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(INT(A1:A100)=TODAY()))`

Answer (score 14):

The new version of Google Sheets has COUNTIFS, which would allow `=COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&TODAY(),A:A,"<"&TODAY()+1)`

You need to opt in to the new version to make it work, though. ("Try the new Google Sheets")

Comment: Minor thing, but I think it would be clearer to represent today as greater than yesterday and less than tomorrow. So: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,">"&TODAY()-1,A:A,"<"&TODAY()+1)`

Comment: @jbyrd Unfortunately that would include all of yesterday as well, except for the exact value of (TODAY()-1) - the stroke of midnight at the start of that day.  To avoid these errors, it's always safest to define a range as (min <= x < max) or equivalently (x>= min AND x < max).  When the business tells you "Monday through Friday", you should implement (MON <= day < SAT).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `COUNTIFS` available, as per `maybeWeCouldStealAVan's` suggestion, then you can use two `COUNTIF` functions like this

`=COUNTIF(A:A,">="&TODAY())-COUNTIF(A:A,">="&TODAY()+1)`

by counting all entries greater than or equal to **today** then subtracting all those greater than or equal to **tomorrow** the result is a count of those on today's date only

That formula will work in Excel or google - another option, similar to Jerry's is to use this googledocs specific formula

`=count(filter(A1:A100,int(A1:A100)=today()))`

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
    dim i as integer
    dim objDate as date
    dim objStartDate as Date
    dim objEndDate as Date
    dim countOrders as integer

    countOrders = 1
    objStartDate = 'the start date to check with ( could be the start of the day)
    objEndDate = 'the end date to check with (could be the end of the day)

    for i = 1 to 'number of rows
        objDate = CDate(cells(i, 1))
        if (objDate > objStartDate) and (objDate < objEndDate) then
            countOrders = countOrder +1
        end if
    next i
```